# Complex number : mth root of nth root

Tags: complex-numbers, nested-radicals

If one defines the $n^{th}$ root of a complex number ($n$ a natural number) so that it coincides with the usual one for the positive real :

- its imaginary part is $\ge 0$
- its real part is the largest among the $n^{th}$ roots whose imaginary part is non-negative.

Is it true that :

$$ \sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{x}} = \sqrt[mn]{x}$$

Comment: For the definition to coincide with the usual one for a positive real, the **real** part must be $\geq 0$, not the imaginary part.  That is, according to "An Intro to Complex Function Theory" (Bruce Palka), you will normally have that the argument of the $n$-th root of $z$, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$,  is in $(-\pi/n, \pi/n].$

Comment: On the basis of my previous comment, for $m,n \in \Bbb{Z_{>1}},~$ I would say that for both the LHS and RHS of the equation in question, the argument, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$ is in $$\left(-\frac{\pi}{mn}, \frac{\pi}{mn}\right].$$

Comment: In other words, you are defining the principal $n$th root as the root with the smallest nonnegative argument. (Note that this definition gives $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ as $e^{i \pi/3}.)$ $\quad$ As for your main question: I believe that is indeed true.

Comment: @user2661923 If so, can you give me a $m$, a $n$ and a $x$ such that $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{x}} \neq \sqrt[mn]{x}$?

Comment: @ Ryan G G I also think it is true, but can't find a proof

Comment: Not possible, under the convention re my first comment.  Let $e^{i\theta}$ denote 
$\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$  Let $z \in \Bbb{C_{\neq 0}}$ be represented by 
$re^{i\theta} ~:~ r > 0.$  For simplicity, assume that $m,n \in \Bbb{Z_{> 1}}.$  
Let $a = z^{1/n} = r^{1/n}e^{i\theta/n}.$  
Let $b = a^{1/m} = r^{1/mn}e^{i\theta/mn}.$
Then, $b^{mn} = z$ and $(-\pi/mn) < (\theta/mn) \leq (\pi/mn).$ ...see next comment

Comment: Furthermore, for any $(mn) = t \in \Bbb{Z_{> 1}}$ the $t$ roots of $z^{1/t}$ will be
given by $r^{1/t}e^{i\theta/t} \times e^{2i\pi k/t}~:~k \in \{0,1,\cdots, (t-1)\}.$
This means that exactly one of the $t$ roots of $z$ will have its argument in
**any** half open interval of length $(2\pi/t)$.  Therefore, since $b$ is such a
root, there can be no other root in $(-pi/t, \pi/t].$  Also, as $b$ is defined,
$b$ does represent the **principal** $t$-th root of $z$.

Comment: the problem is that with my convention $\sqrt{-i}$ is not $\sqrt{2}/2 - i \sqrt{2}/2 $ as in your proof but $-\sqrt{2}/2 + i\sqrt{2}/2 $.

Comment: If I try to rephrase your argument, $\sqrt[mn]{x}$ is the only $mn^{th}$ root $z$ of $x$ such that $arg(z) \in [0, 2\pi/mn]$. If I manage to prove that $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{x}}$ is in there I am done.

Comment: Now, the situation is complicated, because you don't have sufficient reputation points for the online chat, so we have to proceed on this webpage.  Please **be sure** to address comments as @user2661923 so I will be flagged.  Your question did indicate choosing (for example) $w = z^{1/2}$ such that Im$(w) \geq 0$, rather than Re$(w) \geq 0$.  I thought that this was an analytical error on your part, since consistency with Real Analysis would instead require Re$(w) \geq 0$.  However, the analysis that I gave can also be applied to the convention Im$(w) \geq 0.$  Are you sure re this convention?

Comment: To respond, I need to know exactly what your convention is.  You indicated that you are first expressing Arg$(z)$ to be in $[0,2\pi)$.  I assume that this means that if $z = re^{i\theta}$, with $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then the **principal** root of $z^{1/n} = r^{1/n}e^{i\theta/n}.$  This means that your convention is **exactly** the same as mine, except that you are using $[0,2\pi)$, rather than $(-\pi, \pi].$  This means, unless I am mistaken, that **all** of my analysis can also be applied to **your convention**.  Please see if this works for you, and flag me if questions.

Comment: Actually, on reflection, I mis-spoke; I was brainwashed by Palka.  The convention $~0 \leq \theta < 2\pi, ~$ with the principal root of $~[re^{i\theta}]^{1/n}~$ designated as $~r^{1/n}e^{i\theta/n}~$ **is** consistent with Real Analysis, since it (also) sends $~[|x| + i(0)]^{1/n}~$ to $~|x|^{1/n}$.

Comment: Interestingly, in Real Analysis, $(-1)^{1/3}$ is normally regarded as equaling $(-1)$.  In Complex Analysis, neither your convention nor mine will compute the principal root of $(-1)^{1/3}$ as equaling $(-1)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124241/discussion-between-lolo-and-user2661923).

Comment: @Lolo Just woke up - do you still want to chat?